# Ruby Read and Write CSV with Quotes

Tags: ruby, csv

I'd like to read in a csv row, update one field then output the row again with quotes.

```
Row Example Input => "Joe", "Blow", "joe@blow.com"
Desired Row Example Output => "Joe", "Blow", "xxxx@xxxx.xxx"

My script below outputs => Joe, Blow, xxxx@xxxx.xxx
```

It loses the double quotes which I want to retain.

I've tried various options but no joy so far .. any tips?

Many thanks!

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('transactions.csv',
            :quote_char=>'"',
            :col_sep =>",", 
            :headers => true, 
            :header_converters => :symbol ) do |row| 

row[:customer_email] = 'xxxx@xxxx.xxx'

puts row

end
```

Comment: do you want to add quotes if there were none there in the first place?  or will you always have quotes coming in?

Comment: Quotes are there in the first place.

Answer (score 11):

Quotes in CSV fields are usually unnecessary, unless the field itself contains a delimiter or a newline character. But you can force the CSV file to always use quotes. [For that, you need to set `force_quotes => true`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new):

```
CSV.foreach('transactions.csv',
            :quote_char=>'"',
            :col_sep =>",", 
            :headers => true, 
            :force_quotes => true,
            :header_converters => :symbol ) do |row|
```

Comment: :force_quotes => true make no difference to the output

Comment: The quotes are only relevant when writing to a new CSV file, not for output on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add them to all your items

```
Hash[row.map { |k,v| [k,"\"#{v}\""] }]
```

(edited because I forgot you had a hash and not an array)

Comment: Getting close I feel but still no joy. This outputs like "[:customer_email, "xxxx@xxxx.xxx"]"

Comment: Adding row = Hash[row.map { |k,v| [k,"\"#{v}\""] }] before puts row and then output is like: :customer_email=>"\"xxxx@xxxx.xxx\""

Comment: @user1064314 this is expected, as `puts`-ing a hash will give the string literal representation of the keys (ie, what you would type into ruby to get the given string).  If you just `put row[:customer_email]`, you'll see it without the outside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Justin L.

Built on your solution and ended up with this.

I get the feeling Ruby has something more elegant but this does what I need:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('trans.csv',
            :quote_char=>'"',
            :col_sep =>",", 
            :headers => true,
            :header_converters => :symbol ) do |row| 

row[:customer_email] = 'xxxx@xxxx.xxx'

row = Hash[row.map { |k,v| [k,"\"#{v}\""] }]

new_row = ""

row.each_with_index do | (k, v) ,i|
  new_row += v.to_s
  if i != row.length - 1
    new_row += ','
  end
end

puts new_row

end
```