# The issue to write string in double quotes in the CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am going to write a string in double quotes in the CSV using **csv** gem.

```
CSV.open(source_filename, "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["NAME", "AGE"]
  csv << ["Oleg", 15]
end
```

The result is

```
NAME,AGE
Oleg,15
```

What I want to write is that

```
NAME,AGE
"Oleg","15"
```

Is there any way to write like this?

Comment: Wrap your double quotes in single quotes like: '"Olege"', '"15"' or add "force_quotes: true" option to your CSV.open call.  Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079873/ruby-read-and-write-csv-with-quotes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby Read and Write CSV with Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079873/ruby-read-and-write-csv-with-quotes)

Comment: @bkunzi01, thanks for your help. But CSV.foreach(source_filename, :force_quotes => true) do |csv| ... end writes file? I think it loops rows of file.

Comment: @bkunzi01, I am going to write to the new file, not reading the existing file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want literal quotes in the values, but simply want to wrap all values with quotes you can do so by setting the `force_quotes` option:

```
csv = CSV.generate(force_quotes: true) do |csv|
  csv << ["NAME", "AGE"]
  csv << ["Oleg", 15]
end

puts csv
```

Prints:

```csv
"NAME","AGE"
"Oleg","15"
```

I use `generate` in this answer to simplify copy/pasting the code. You can use the same options with `open`. This then becomes `CSV.open(source_filename, "wb", force_quotes: true)`.

However when the above is read by an CSV implementation the quotes will not be part of the value. This is further explained by the [answer of tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59183769/3982562).

Answer (score 1):

The minimal form is this:

```
NAME,AGE
Oleg,15
```

The quoted form is:

```
NAME,AGE
"Oleg","15"
```

However quotes are only necessary when the content contains something *irregular* like a `,`, or a `"`. They're not introduced unless necessary in order to conserve space in the resulting CSV document. All those extra quotes can bloat the file if they serve no practical purpose.

If you want *literal quotes* in the value, that is you want the value to be `"Oleg"` with quotes around it, not just from the point of how it appears in the CSV file, then you need to do this:

```
NAME,AGE
"""Oleg""","""15"""
```

Where `"..."` represents a quoted CSV string and `""` within a string represents a single `"` in the value. As such you see triple, in the form `"("")...("")"`. The details of why is explained in the [CSV specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

In my experience Ruby's CSV library gets it right so it's best to trust it with whatever data you have. For example:

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << [ 'Name', 'Age' ]
  csv << [ 'Alice', 29 ]
  csv << [ 'Brent', 31 ]
  csv << [ 'Cathy Dint', 21 ]
  csv << [ 'Daryl "Darby" Everest', 62 ]
  csv << [ "Captain\nNewline", 32 ]
end

puts csv
```

The end result looks like:

```
Name,Age
Alice,29
Brent,31
Cathy Dint,21
"Daryl ""Darby"" Everest",62
"Captain
Newline",32
```

Notice how the newline is handled. CSV is not as simple as you'd think.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find a small code snippet which will help you to write what you need.

```
CSV.open("abc.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["NAME", "AGE"]
  csv << ["\"Oleg\"", "\"15\""]
end
```

Below you can find output screenshot

[image]

Comment: I am getting like this. 
NAME,AGE
"""Oleg""","""15"""